# Why do they add a # sign in routing angular apps?

Tags: angularjs

Ex from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
    <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Angular 1.07... who knows=)

Comment: It is because angular uses "name anchors" those existed in HTML since I can remember. If the anchor is on the same page it does not post to the server or ask the server to resend content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs is a framework that uses html, css, and Javascript in order to easily create single-page applications.

Single-page applications are websites which fit on a single web page, in order to give the user a more fluid experience. All of the necessary code (html, Javascript etc.) is loaded all at once, and additional items are loaded from the server as necessary. The page does not need to be refreshed.

The "#" symbol in html tells the page to redirect to another section on that page. Since AngularJs works with single page applications, the "#" is telling the application to redirect and route to a new page view from within the webpage.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating